# Iteration converging to 0

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

I have a question: Why does this variation of Newton's iteration 
$x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \frac{f(x_{k})}{f'(x_k)}$, converge to a pole? My understanding of a pole is that it is the point at which the equation approaches infinity. I also believe that I need to expand the convergence with a Taylor series, but I am struggling on how to exactly prove WHY this formula converges to a pole. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Suppose that $\lim x_n$ exists. Then,$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$Either $f\to0$ faster than $f'$, or $|f'|\to\infty$ faster than $f$.

Answer (score 1):

This iteration is Newton's method on the function $g(x) = 1/f(x)$, since $g(x)/g'(x) = -f(x)/f'(x)$.